# How can I get selected row using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

This is my table row within the `tbody` of my table. I get dropdown value, text value but I can't get selected row value. My row value returns "undefined".

```js
$(document).on("click", "#skorKartDegerle", function() {
  $("#modal_evaluation").modal("show");
});

$(document).on("click", "#btnKaydet", function() {
  var arrList = [];
  var isEmptyAnswer = false;

  $("#evaluationTable > tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var line = $(this).find(".answerLine").val();
    var ddlVal = $(this).find(".answerddl").val();
    var txtVal = $(this).find(".answertxt").val();

    var obj = '{"line":"' + line + '","ddlVal":"' + ddlVal + '","txtVal":"' + txtVal + '"}';
    arrList.push(obj);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="answerLine" value="2">
      <td>FR002</td>
      <td>Koton Mağazacılık</td>
      <td>1800</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Kabul</td>
      <td class="select" value="0">
        <select class="answerddl">
          <option value="1">Kabul</option>
          <option value="2">Ret</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="answertxt"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please create a complete working snippet with tools `<>`

Comment: show your jsp code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the issue is because `tr` elements do not have a `value` attribute. To do what you require you could use a `data` attribute instead, to store custom metadata on the element. The other part is that `this` is a reference to the `tr` element. You're then calling `find()` on the element you're looking to target, so it will not be found as that method looks for descendants only.

In addition it's worth noting that you can make the logic more succinct by using `map()` to build the array instead of explicitly looping with `each()` and also that it would be better practice to store objects in the array and only JSON encode it before transferring via AJAX.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#btnKaydet", function() {
  var isEmptyAnswer = false;

  let arrList = $("#evaluationTable > tbody > tr").map((i, tr) => {
    let $tr = $(tr);
    return {
      line: $tr.data('value'),
      ddlVal: $tr.find(".answerddl").val(),
      txtVal: $tr.find(".answertxt").val()
    }
  }).get();
  
  console.log(arrList);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="evaluationTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="answerLine" data-value="2">
      <td>FR002</td>
      <td>Koton Mağazacılık</td>
      <td>1800</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Kabul</td>
      <td class="select" value="0">
        <select class="answerddl">
          <option value="1">Kabul</option>
          <option value="2">Ret</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="answertxt"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="btnKaydet">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I've changed as you show, but I still get row as "undefined"

Comment: Make it a runnable snippet or use jsfiddle.net

Comment: @FSDford and Rory, when I use run code snippet below your code as you see line still undefined.

Comment: Thank you It works but it doesn't work in my ide. Can you share chat link with me? If you check my code it would be better

Comment: Please add your complete code to the question. In addition, check the console for errors

Comment: Actually I've added all of code that related my question. If I add my whole JSP and Java code it would be more than 1000 lines of code. There is no error on my console. I've get line as undefined.

Comment: Only need to see the generated HTML and jQuery.